# Key appears to be malformed, or is passphrase-protected

Tags: ssl, heroku

I do not have set and passphrase while creating certificate. And I have this error message then I try to install this certificate on heroku.

```
$ heroku certs:add server.crt server.key
Resolving trust chain... failed
> Key appears to be malformed, or is passphrase-protected.
```

Here is result content of the folder:

```
$ ls -l
total 24
-rw-r--r--  1 dkaigorodov  staff  2702 Apr 13 18:01 bundle.pem
-rw-r--r--  1 dkaigorodov  staff  1855 Apr 13 18:06 server.crt
-rw-r--r--  1 dkaigorodov  staff  1681 Apr 13 18:06 server.key
```

I bought certificate from http://dnsimple.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I used Vim editor to save the certificates. 
I changed the editor, problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

Try including the intermediate cert in the upload:

```
heroku certs:add server.crt bundle.pem server.key
```

Hope this helps!

Alex

Answer (score 1):

## Installing dnsimple/comodo certs on heroku:

- 1. save key from dnsimple as "server.key"
- 2. save cert from dnsimple as "server.crt"
- 3. download intermediate certs: `curl https://gist.github.com/rwdaigle/5503531/raw/bundle.pem > bundle.pem`
- 4. install keys on heroku: `$ heroku certs:add server.crt server.key`

## Sources:

- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-certificate-dnsimple
- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-endpoint